# Leftmost outermost Reduction (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, reduction

i got the task to use the leftmost outermost reduction on following expression:

```
f inc expo 9 (f (*2) expo 3 1)
```

inc is defined as:

```
 inc :: Int -> Int
 inc x = x+1
```

expo is defined as:

```
expo :: Int -> Int
expo x = expo (x*2)
```

and f as:

```
f :: (Int->Int) -> (Int-> Int) -> Int -> Int -> Int
f g h a b = g(a-b)
```

I have absolutely no clue where to start the reduction with more functions. I read the hint that the redex is not contained in any other redexes, but i dont get it ;(.

I would appreciate every tip/help.

Comment: from your definition of `expo` it will never terminate

Comment: Actually, it will, since expo (`h` in `f`'s definition) is never used (i.e. never applied to anything).

Comment: That means i start the reduction with the f function?  Means inc is the "g", expo the "h", 9 the "a" and the rest "b"?

Comment: look at the equation `f g h a b = g(a-b)` and see what g h a b are in `f inc expo 9 (f (*2) expo 3 1)`. This will produce some expression using `inc`, `expo`, `9` and `(f (*2) expo 3 1)`. The next step is to perform the reduction (substitution, if you will) without which you cannot compute g (a-b). So on, until you get a value of type `Int` (or a function, but in this case you will get a Int)

Comment: @fjh english is an annoying language.  what I meant is 'from your definition of `expo` `expo` will never terminate'

Answer (score 1):

The first (leftmost, outermost) reduction for

```
f inc expo 9 (f (*2) expo 3 1)
```

is to apply the definition of `f`, once, where `f g h a b = g(a-b)` so we use `g` as `inc`, `a` as `9` and `b` as `(f (*2) expo 3 1)`, giving

```
inc(9 - (f (*2) expo 3 1))
```

Now we're actually done with the question we were asked. That's the leftmost, outermost reduction made. Notice that we didn't need to use any facts about the other functions, which is probably what the hint was getting at.